# Why would a class be unable to be cast to an interface it implements?

Tags: java, apache, websphere

I'm trying to get an application to work on websphere, and eclipse shows I have no errors.  Despite that, when I try to start the application I get an error saying the Web application failed to start because `org.apache.myfaces.ee6.MyFacesContainerInitializer` can't be cast to the interface `javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer`.  I did some digging and found that MyFacesContainerInitializer implements ServletContainerInitializer, so I know it's not a problem of this being a subclass that's expected to implement it but doesn't.  As far as I can see there's no reason this should fail.  What am I missing?

If it helps, here is what I get when I try to run the app.

```
[ERROR   ] SRVE0015E: Failure to initialize Web application MEFILESWeb
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer: Provider org.apache.myfaces.ee6.MyFacesContainerInitializer could not be instantiated: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast class org.apache.myfaces.ee6.MyFacesContainerInitializer to interface javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer
  at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:235)
  at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:192)
  at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:381)
  at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:449)
  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initializeServletContainerInitializers(WebApp.java:2058)
  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:743)
  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:5779)
  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost.createRunnableHandler(DynamicVirtualHost.java:249)
  at [internal classes]
```

As Sheetal said, the problem was that I was missing some files in my WebSphere library.  Once they were put in, the problem is gone.

Comment: Compare libs in /WEB-INF/lib or in Tomcat's /lib, there is a clash.

Comment: @SheetalMohanSharma Where is Tomcat's /lib kept?  I'm having trouble finding it.

Comment: Sorry  websphere lib files

Comment: Do you have a copy of javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer in your application? Do you have parent Last classloading order created.

Comment: If the problem is fixed you should put your fix in an answer and accept that answer. This may help others who have the problem in the future; right now only a careful reading of your question would show that a) you're not still in search of an answer or b) what that answer was.

Answer (score 1):

There were some .object and .properties files missing from my websphere folder. When I put them in the project runs fine. The specific files were visible in eclipse under the project folder. This answer will be accepted as soon as it can be, no more answers are necessary.